# How to get 64-bit binaries from GHC for Snow Leopard?

Tags: haskell, 64-bit, osx-snow-leopard, ghc, haskell-platform

I've recently upgraded my OS to Snow Leopard, which broke my GHC.  I was able to fix it on one machine by adding flags for 32-bit compiles in /usr/bin/ghc (something like -optl -m32 -opta -m32 -optc -m32, gathered from [here](http://old.nabble.com/Snow-Leopard-Breaks-GHC-td25198347.html)).  Now I can't get it to produce 64-bit binaries for my other machine, which supports 64-bits.  The 32-bit flags break, and removing them breaks as well.  Any tips?

When I try to compile I get stuff like this:

```
/var/folders/az/az3Ef9shFZq6RajmTEBwu++++TI/-Tmp-//ghc8006_0/ghc8006_0.s:212:0:
32-bit absolute addressing is not supported for x86-64

/var/folders/az/az3Ef9shFZq6RajmTEBwu++++TI/-Tmp-//ghc8006_0/ghc8006_0.s:212:0:
cannot do signed 4 byte relocation

/var/folders/az/az3Ef9shFZq6RajmTEBwu++++TI/-Tmp-//ghc8006_0/ghc8006_0.s:215:0:
32-bit absolute addressing is not supported for x86-64

/var/folders/az/az3Ef9shFZq6RajmTEBwu++++TI/-Tmp-//ghc8006_0/ghc8006_0.s:215:0:
cannot do signed 4 byte relocation
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64 bit Snow Leopard installers for the Haskell Platform are available, as of 2011.

- http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/mac.html

[image: Haskell Platform]

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that at the moment ghc cannot generate correct 64 bit binaries under Snow Leopard. This appears to be in part because of a bug in its 64 bit link generation and in part because of a change in the native toolchain. The workaround you mention simply tells it to generate a 32 bit target and thus won't be part of any actual solution to your problem.

Comment: Lame!  I guess I'll have to develop on my 32-bit machine.

Thanks for the response, I'll mark it as answered if I don't hear anything more promising by tomorrow ^_^

Comment: @paul.meier: You can still work on a 64-bit machine. You just need to have GHC generate 32-bit binaries. I have GHC on my Core 2 Duo MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard and it compiles just fine with the appropriate flags set.